# Display current pane's current directory in status

Tags: tmux

Is there a way to update `pwd` in tmux status, instead of showing it in PS1?

```
set -g status-left "#(pwd)"
set -g status-interval 1
```

doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

`set -g status-left '#(pwd)'` does set the pwd for me but it looks like that is a separate shell to the sessions you have open so always remains in `/home/$user`

You can `set -g set-titles-string '#(pwd)'` and that will follow your sessions.

Comment: Think it should be `'#(pwd)'` in 2nd snippet